How do I run code before useEffect code gets executed?
So today i've found a javascript api for DOOM and I can run it just fine in html.
But when I try to do the same in React (as a Mendix component) I don't know what to do, useEffect always seems to load in the script first before  gets the chance to load in, which breaks the game.
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export function DoomGame({ sampleText }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "https://js-dos.com/cdn/js-dos-api.js";
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = () => {
            const dosbox = new window.Dosbox({
                id: "dosbox",
                onload: function (dosbox) {
                    dosbox.run("upload/DOOM-@evilution.zip", "./doom");
                },
                onrun: function (dosbox, app) {
                    console.log("App '" + app + "' is run");
                }
            });
        };

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleFullscreen = () => {
        if (window.dosbox) {
            window.dosbox.requestFullScreen();
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div id="dosbox"></div>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={handleFullscreen}>Make fullscreen</button>
        </>
    );
}


Admittedly I turned to chatgpt first to get my hopes up, but to no avail.
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function DoomGame() {
    const dosboxRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Load jQuery
        const jqueryScript = document.createElement('script');
        jqueryScript.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js";
        jqueryScript.async = true;
        jqueryScript.onload = () => {
            // Load js-dos-api.js after jQuery is loaded
            const dosboxScript = document.createElement('script');
            dosboxScript.src = "https://js-dos.com/cdn/js-dos-api.js";
            dosboxScript.async = true;
            dosboxScript.onload = () => {
                const dosbox = new window.Dosbox({
                    id: "dosbox",
                    onload: function (dosbox) {
                        dosbox.run("upload/DOOM-@evilution.zip", "./doom");
                    },
                    onrun: function (dosbox, app) {
                        console.log("App '" + app + "' is run");
                    }
                });
                window.dosboxInstance = dosbox; // Store dosbox instance globally to use in handleFullscreen
            };

            document.body.appendChild(dosboxScript);
        };

        document.body.appendChild(jqueryScript);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(jqueryScript);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleFullscreen = () => {
        const dosboxInstance = window.dosboxInstance;
        if (dosboxInstance) {
            dosboxInstance.requestFullScreen();
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="dosbox" ref={dosboxRef} className="dosbox-container"></div>
            <br />
            <button onClick={handleFullscreen}>Make fullscreen</button>
        </div>
    );
}


If I use this I immediately run into a client script error

Why don't you load the script in your website, before React, that way it is globally accessible?

jQuery should be a peer-dependency of your React component, along with Dosbox (js-dos-api).

try replacing useEffect with useLayoutEffect
